# div inside a paragraph that is inside a table data. Does it work?

Tags: html, css, class

Can you have inside a table, in a td a p with a class and inside this paragraph a portion of the text with a div with a class ?

Like the incomplete and short example here under ? Because from my experience it is not working.

```
<table id="tSignature">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="logo.gif" />
            </td>
            <td class="withoutBorder">
                <p class="signature">
                    <div class="colorBold">John Smith</div><br />
                    President
                </p>
```

Thanks for the help.

Andrew

Comment: Yes it is valid HTML

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is something not working in your project? Or is this question about the syntactical nature of HTML?